# JQuery slide subsequent elements together with current element

Tags: jquery, slide

How do I achieve the following **slide left** effect with JQuery?

1. I have a couple of `div` elements floating left to each other.
2. I would like to apply a *slide left* action on the first element (most left element).
3. The remaining elements should *slide* together and not JUMP after the animation has completed. (the **jump is my problem**)

I can get it work with `toggle` and sliding up but I need it to slide left and not up/down.

Here is a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philipf/6y5U2/7/)**.

**JavaScript:**

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#page1').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button>Slide left</button>

<div class='container'>
    <div id='page1'>
        Content 123
    </div>

    <div id='page2'>
        Content 456
    </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container div { float:left; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#page1').animate({'margin-left': '-100px'}, 1000, 
    function() {$(this).hide();}
);
```

In principal, use animate.